# Does counterspelling as an immediate action allows you to cast another spell the same turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, actions, counterspelling, immediate-actions

I have this doubt. For what I have been reading it seems so, indeed you can counterspell and cast the same turn. So, whoever can counter as an immediate action like the abjurer (counterspell) or the arcanist with the Counterspell exploit is able to do both actions.

I have an example which suits this case perfectly:

In the feat Quicken Spell it is said that, as a swift action, you can cast an extra spell that turn.

According to Pathfinder's rules, swift actions and immediate actions are similar, they both happen too fast and don't disturb your round's main action, the difference being that immediate actions can be done in other player's turns.

That being said, it seems reasonable to me that those special cases of counterspelling could be done without interfering in the character's turn main action (full round or standard) just like Quicken Spell does.

So, can a character which can counter a spell as an immediate action still cast his turn's spell normally?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, you can

Using an Immediate action will consume your next turn's Swift action, not affecting any of your other actions. So, after a counterspell, you could not use an ability that requires a Swift action (like casting a quickened spell), but could move and cast any spells that require a Standard action normally. Or even begin a full round spell (like *Summon Monster*).

This is a common *house rule*, but many people allow to *downgrade* a better action into a smaller action, which is normally allowed only for standard actions to move actions by the rules. So, this would allow you to still use an ability that requires a Swift action by downgrading your move or standard actions. There is also a [magic item](http://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Corset%20of%20Delicate%20Moves) that allows downgrading like this once per day.